# Problem to structure property of an object using [apollo / graphql]

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

**Problem**

*Hello friends,*

*I am working on an api using Apollo Server.*
*I am having the problem of how to display the `nextEpisodeDate` property only once. My solution shows `nextEpisodeDate` in all sub-array in the `episodes` property and it shouldn't be like that.*

*I hope someone can help me !*

**JSON Example**

```
"episodes": [
   {
     "nextEpisodeDate": "2020-01-17"
   },
   {
     "episode": 3,
     "id": "53789/dorohedoro-3",
     "imagePreview": "https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/3274/3/th_3.jpg"
   },
   {
     "episode": 2,
     "id": "53755/dorohedoro-2",
     "imagePreview": "https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/3274/2/th_3.jpg"
   },
   {
     "episode": 1,
     "id": "53705/dorohedoro-1",
     "imagePreview": "https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/3274/1/th_3.jpg"
   }
 ]
```

**typeDefs**

```
const resolvers = require('./resolvers');
const {gql} = require('apollo-server');

const typeDefs = gql `
  extend type Query{
    latest_anime: [Animes]
  }

  type Animes{
    title: String
    poster: String
    synopsis: String
    debut: String
    type: String
    rating: String
    genres: [String]
    episodes: [Episodes]
  }

  type Episodes{
    nextEpisodeDate: String
    episode: String
    id: String
    imagePreview: String
  }
`

module.exports = {
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
};
```

**Apollo Playground**

```
query{
  latest_anime{
    title
    poster
    synopsis
    debut
    type
    rating
    genres
    episodes{
      nextEpisodeDate
      episode
      id
      imagePreview
    }
  }
}
```

**Apollo Playground Output**

```
{
  "data": {
    "latest_anime": [
      {
        "title": "Tsugumomo OVA",
        "poster": "https://animeflv.net/uploads/animes/covers/3275.jpg",
        "synopsis": "OVA 4.6Kazuya Kagami nunca va a ningún lado sin su preciada “Sakura Obi” que su madre le regaló. Un día, una hermosa chica vestida con un kimono llamada Kiriha aparece ante él. Naturalmente, ella comienza a vivir en su habitación. ¿Naturalmente? ¡Esto solo es el inicio de la embarazosa y confusa...",
        "debut": null,
        "type": "OVA",
        "rating": "4.6",
        "genres": [
          "accion",
          "comedia",
          "ecchi",
          "escolares",
          "seinen",
          "sobrenatural"
        ],
        "episodes": [
          {
            "nextEpisodeDate": null,
            "episode": null,
            "id": null,
            "imagePreview": null
          },
          {
            "nextEpisodeDate": null,
            "episode": "1",
            "id": "53753/tsugumomo-ova-1",
            "imagePreview": "https://cdn.animeflv.net/screenshots/3275/1/th_3.jpg"
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: working fine, `Episodes` type contains `nextEpisodeDate`, ... query (fields you're asking for) contains `nextEpisodeDate` - then provided - `null` returned if undefined

Comment: @xadm I understand, but this property is supposed to only appear in the initial index and not in all the indexes of the array.

Comment: resolver MUST return typed (with defined structure) object

Comment: @xadm Yes, but I still think I'll leave it that way. On the client side I can specify if the value is different from null. Otherwise, I ignore it.

Comment: sure, even in JSX f.e. `{nextEpisodeDate && <NextDate date={nextEpisodeDate}/>}

Comment: Exactly, thanks for your example!

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can get the desired response structure is to have two separate types. A field must have exactly one type, but you can use an abstract type like a union or interface in order to have each individual item in the list resolve to one of multiple types at runtime.

```
type AiredEpisode implements Episode {
  id: String
  episode: String
  imagePreview: String
}

type UpcomingEpisode implements Episode {
  id: String
  nextEpisodeDate: String
}

interface Episode {
  id: String
}

type Anime {
  episodes: [Episode]
  # other fields
}
```

You would then query the episodes like this:

```
query {
  latest_anime {
    episodes {
      # fields on the interface itself like id are common to all
      # implementing types so they don't need to be inside a fragment
      id
      # fields specific to one of the types need to be inside a fragment
      ... on UpcomingEpisode {
        nextEpisodeDate
      }
      ... on AiredEpisode {
        id
        episode
        imagePreview
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Side note: if your API doesn't return an `id` for the upcoming episodes, you should still provide one (you could use the show's id, for example, you just want to make sure it's unique). This will ensure that you don't run into caching issues if you use a client like Apollo on the front end.